# Why do I have so many Doges?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm playing CK2 as a Merchant Republic, and somehow I've managed to create a second set of great houses. It is an Ironman game, so I can't go back to a previous save but I'd really like to get rid of the new set of houses. Do I have to murder a whole family (or would that just replace them as normal when you have five)?

I think I did it by winning a crusade for Andalusia and then giving a republic to my heir. I think that may have resulted in another set of Merchant Republic houses spawning, but I'm not positive.

Any advice on how to get rid of the extra houses or from now on is the competition for doge that much more competitive? I'm currently on patch 2.1.6 (TTXL).

[image: 10 Great houses in a single republic]

Comment: Wow. So republic. Much prestige.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, well I'm not sure of the exact cause of the multiple houses, but I can confirm that if one is completely eliminated they do not create another house.

Now, if you will excuse me I'm off to do some "house" cleaning.

After a bit more murder, it does look like I was able to set it back to 5 houses by murdering everyone:
[image]

Comment: As I understand it, there isn't a single diplomatic problem in CK2 you can't solve with enough murder...

Comment: I've had this happen when conquering one merchant republic using Roman Reconquest (I was Venice->Byzantine->Reformed Roman Empire). It kind of was my fault actually, since I was creating new republics by releasing them as independent, farming them for their trade posts, and then reconquering them when they were used up. I have no idea what caused this to happen for one of the republics (but not the others).

Comment: I was able to murder away four of the extra houses, but couldn't get rid of the last one, which kept respawning. I think that was because it was the only house that was able to build a trade post before I noticed the problem and started stabbing.

Comment: @Affine: Ah interesting, I'll confirm here shortly. I've only got one "extra" house at the moment. There has been a lot of shoddy balcony construction lately if you know what I mean.